# Problem with netlink socket: kernel freeze

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, netlink

I'm trying to use netlink sockets to exchange messages between user-space and kernel space...i send a message from user-space to kernel-space and all works well but when i try to reply from kernel-space, system freezes. In particular i schedule with a workqueue a function that create the message and send to user-space using netlink_unicast function...here some kernel code:

```
void wq_func(struct work_queue *wq)
{
  struct sk_buff *resp = alloc_skb(NLMSG_LENGTH(100), GFP_KERNEL);
  if (!resp)
  {
     printk(KERN_INFO "alloc_skb failed");
     return;
  }

  struct nlmsghdr *nlh = (struct nlmsghdr *)skb_put(resp, NLMSG_LENGTH(100));
  memset(nlh, 0, NLMSG_LENGTH(100));
  nlh->nlmsg_len = NLMSG_LENGTH(100);
  nlh->nlmsg_pid = 0;
  nlh->nlmsg_flags = 0;
  strcpy(NLMSG_DATA(nlh), "From kernel: Yes i'm here!");
  NETLINK_CB(resp).pid = 0;
  NETLINK_CB(resp).dst_group = 0;

  printk(KERN_INFO "Trying to send a netlink message to pid %d", pid);
  int err = netlink_unicast(s, resp, pid, MSG_DONTWAIT);
  if (err < 0)
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Error sending message to user-space");
  kfree_skb(resp);
}
DECLARE_WORK(wq, wq_func);

static void input_nl(struct sk_buff *buff)
{
  printk(KERN_INFO "Received message socket NETLINK_TEST");
  if (buff == NULL)
  {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "NULL sk_buff!");
    return;
  }
  struct nlmsghdr *nlh = (struct nlmsghdr *)buff->data;
  printk(KERN_INFO "Received netlink message from pid %d: %s", nlh->nlmsg_pid,       NLMSG_DATA(nlh));

  pid = nlh->nlmsg_pid;

  schedule_work(&wq);
}

int __init knl_init()
{
  printk(KERN_INFO "knl module loaded");

  s = netlink_kernel_create(&init_net, NETLINK_TEST, 0, input_nl, NULL, THIS_MODULE);

  if (s == NULL)
    return -1;
  return 0;
}
```

If i try to comment the call to netlink_unicast kernel doesn't freeze. From user-space i can send a message correctly. I remember that the same code worked well in the past and i 'm very surprised about this strange error now.

Any idea?

Thank you all!

---

I tried to remove kfree_skb call after netlink_unicast call and all works...so, why the system hangs with that call? Where should i free allocated sk_buff?

Comment: netlink became internally synchronous at some point, try without `schedule_work()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`netlink_unicast()` takes ownership of the `skb` and frees it itself.

Comment: Ah ok...this was a missing concept!Thanks caf!

Answer (score 0):

After calling `netlink_unicast` you cannot free `struct sk_buff`